# ¿Se puede insertar una imagen en un pdf usando Google Apps Script?

Tags: imagen, pdf, google-apps-script

He estado buscando una manera de insertar una imagen en un pdf usando Google Apps Script, no he conseguido manera de hacerlo, ni he encontrado biblioteca, ni servicio aunque sea de pago.
Consigo llegar al blob del archivo, pero a partir de ahí no consigo que hacer con ello. Las IAs me dicen de usar métodos que no funcionan.

```
function imagen_a_pdf() {
   var documentoPDF = DriveApp.getFolderById("1dJIgubCMdTKQBkRsubH0mt7iH0Kn3I9j").getFilesByName("pruebapdf.pdf").next()
   var idDocumentoPDF = documentoPDF.getId()
  var blobPDF = DriveApp.getFileById(idDocumentoPDF).getAs('application/pdf');
   Logger.log(blobPDF)
}
```

Esto es lo que uso para llegar al blob, pero desde ahí no llego a mas.

Answer (score 0):

mediante la librería pdf-lib, pude insertar imágenes y textos, te paso enlaces con mucha información

https://github.com/tanaikech/PDFApp
https://pdf-lib.js.org/

Espero sean de utilidad.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).